# Dialogflow functions: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I've finally got user signed up with this cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {
  dialogflow,
  Image,
} = require('actions-on-google')

// Create an app instance

const app = dialogflow()

// Register handlers for Actions SDK intents

app.intent('test', conv => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn());
})

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

But right after that i'm getting the same error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
    at Function.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:120:71)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:22:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:18:12)
    at Function.handler (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:84:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:55:32)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:22:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:18:12)
    at standard (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:51:41)
```

It doesn't even get to the `console.log('test')`:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google')

// Create an app instance

const app = dialogflow()

// Register handlers for Actions SDK intents

app.intent('test', conv => {
  console.log('test')
  conv.ask(`response`)
})

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "2.1.3",
    "firebase-admin": "5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "1.0.3",
    "dialogflow": "0.5.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "0.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens with the second code?

Comment: any code, that uses `dialogflow` from `actions-on-google`, throws the error `Cannot read property 'client' of undefined`

Comment: Can you update your question to include the contents of your package.json?

Comment: @Prisoner it's done

Comment: Is it throwing this error when you start the client, or when you try to do something?

Comment: it throwing this error when i'm calling for the intent, that is using this funciton

Comment: Sorry, this is a wild guess. I was searching for "client" in the dialogflow.ts source code: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/master/src/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.ts#L416 was the only reference I could find. It seems to be talking about authentication. Not an answer - but something that might be related.

Comment: I also encountered the same problem, ***not once but twice.***
The first time it was the problem with my CLIENT_ID. As I viewed it in Actions on Google Console in [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2DZN.png) the **CLIENT_ID** is partially visible and is non-selectable, thus I copied it partially (as I wasn't aware) and encountered the errors. After hours of searching and luckily trying AoG console on [Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX3J5.png), I found that the **CLIENT_ID** part scrolls and has a certain length. The second time it happened as I saved my **CLIENT_ID** in another fil

Answer (score 11):

goto your action on google app **Develop** section, goto account linking, expand **Google Sign In Client Information** you will see **Client ID issued by Google to your Actions** copy that client id.

when initializing your app in

```
const app = dialogflow();
```

pass in an object with your actions on google account linking client id

your code should look like:

```
const app = dialogflow({
   clientId : YOUR_APPS_CLIENT_ID
})
```

This will fix this issue.

To Get YOUR_APPS_CLIENT_ID, go to actions on google console, on the left nav menu, under advanced options, go to account linking and expand the third card to get your id.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: after a long time it worked for me, but literally I don't know what mistake i was doing, it just worked as it is, may be updating `actions-on-google` library made it work for me

Answer (score 0):

**Update for September 2019**

If you can't find your **Client ID** (as it was for me, because it seems Google doesn't show it anymore within the "Google Sign In Client Information" card), then go to your **[Google Cloud Platform](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?authuser=0)** console and under **APIs and Services** menu, open the **Credentials** screen.

Then scroll to the **OAuth 2.0 client IDs** section and find "New Actions on Google App". The value in the last column is your Client ID for Actions on Google project.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Google has updated their accountlinking settings again in October 2019. You can now also find the Client ID under the Google Sign-in details in your Google project. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58063700/6351280

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I didnt want to accountlink in a test project of mine, I had left accountlinking on from when I was testing something. When I connected a webhook without any clientID in the code I got the error. All I had to do was clear the accountlink settings from the Google project and then everything was solved.

[image]