# Unable to see client id

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We are trying to setup the account linking process using [Google SignIn](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in).

In this, it asks us to copy the Client Id at Step 5:

> 5. Open Client Information and take note of the value of Client ID issued by Google to your Actions.

However, I don't find the Client ID field in the Account Linking section at all.

Is there an alternative way to generate this? I tried using the console in developers.google.com and created an Oauth 2.0 Client Id of Web Application type, but using the Client ID generated this way, gives the following error (when used with DialogFlow):

```
Error: Wrong recipient, payload audience != requiredAudience
    at OAuth2Client.verifySignedJwtWithCerts (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:696:23)
    at OAuth2Client.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:514:38)
    at step (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:57:23)
    at Object.next (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:38:53)
    at fulfilled (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:29:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

The documentation seems to be outdated and there is no information anywhere on how to get the Client Id

Answer (score 0):

**Update October 2019**

It seems that Google has updated this, you can see your client ID again under the google Sign-in option in your Google Project.

[image]

---

You can see the client ID in the [Google APIs overview](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?authuser=0).

In the top left, select the project for which you want to get the client ID and then under the **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs** section you should be able to see all ID's connected to your project.

Google should have already generated one for you named "New Actions On Google App". I've also had older projects where it had more than one key and it would only work with the other key.

This has been updated recently and it seems that the documentation isn't up to date yet.